# Sending Email Notification Privilege

Tags: oracle, privilege

I have stored procedure run weekly. I would like to set job scheduler to send a email notification whether the procedure failed or not.

It seems like I need the privilege from DBA to create those job.

What is the name of the privilege  I should ask to DBA?

Comment: The dbms_scheduler can send email notifications, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72277) for more.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE JOB - See following link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin007.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dbms_scheduler chain, in which the exit status of the procedure then determines whether "success" or "failure" actions are taken.

Anyway, tell your DBA what you want to do and ask for the privileges that would be required.

Comment: Bomber.... my DBA says NO...   Is there any way around to send automation email?  It does not have to be from the Database.

Comment: One option would be to run the procedure from a cron job, set an exit code, and use that to send an email. Tell the boss it's less secure, less reliable, and not integrated with the database, and if that's a problem then talk to the DBA for another alternative.